# How to save all cached images in Chrome using Developer Tools

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools

/I need to save all cached images in Chrome to local folder. I have in `Developer Tools` in `Recources > Frames > Folder123 > Images` a lot of images. It's extremely slow to save each one as : 1. `Open in a new tab` 2. and then `Save as...`. Is there any was to get all images much faster?

UPDATE:

Maybe this can be done using Firefox more easily?

Comment: typing `about:Cache` in a new Chrome window will give you a list of all the URLs in the cache.  Perhaps that's useful?  (I went looking for the files themselves, but didn't find them)

Comment: This is faster:
> Open up an Explorer Window with the download target folder
> Drag it to the left side of the screen
> Open up your Developer Tools window with the images and drag that window to the right of the screen

Now you can start:
For each image:
> Doubleclick on it (automatically opens in new tab)
> Drag it to your explorer window (download ready)
Repeat this fast process for each image.
You can also skip doubleclick and drag it immediately, but then you don't have the original file name, but that also downloads succesfully and works even faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you used a page downloader: www.httrack.com/ it safes the whole webpage and also the pictures.
 This could be the reason for your problem. More efficient and easier to handle